# email in .net - c#

Tags: c#, .net

this is probably an easy one, I just dont know what it is!
Im trying to add the contents of a field from a query to the 1st line of an email in c#, then have a new line for the rest of the body.

```
nmail.Body = i.bDesc + MsgBody.Text;
```

So Id want to put the carriage return between i.bDesc and MsgBody.Text,
Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

thanks

Comment: Do you want the email body to be plain text or HTML?

Comment: I have a version of each, one with an image one without, Ive got it working with both, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nmail.Body = i.bDesc + System.Environment.NewLine + MsgBody.Text ;
```

Answer (score 0):

nmail.Body = i.bDesc + "\r\n" + MsgBody.Text;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\r\n` for a new line, which is the equivalent of VbCrLf in vb.net. Aducci has given a good cross-language answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
nmail.Body = i.bDesc + "\r\n" + MsgBody.Text;
```

Or...

```
nmail.Body = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}",i.bDesc,MsgBody.Text);
```